# Reading and writing to NFC

Tags: java, android, nfc

I am writing an Android application to read and write to a tag. When I read everything's works fine, when i try to save data on the nfc tag, tag first read data and opens again activity, how to block reading from intent and save correctly data?

I have an activity that runs 4 fragments, the reading code is in the activity and the mechanism of writing is called from fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For writing I would not use the `enableForegroundDispatch` method, it misleads the user to move the card out of range too quickly, leading to lots of write errors and data corruption when used by real users.

This is because the sound prompt happens straight after the OS has read the card before your code has a chance to write to it.

I would use `enableReaderMode` instead where you get to control the sound prompt.

**Update**
Note with `enabledReaderMode` you can still put Intent filters in your manifest to ask the Android OS to start your App when it sees a certain type of Tag, Intents generated from Manifest Intent filters are always handled in the `onCreate` method of your Activity no matter how you are handling cards in your Activity.

Also `enableForegroundDispatch` is unreliable for reading as well, because the OS handles the NFC reading in what looks like a windowless Activity, your Activity will get Paused while it does the read.

I have had with real user testing with `enableForegroundDispatch` the tag coming in to range when your App is in the foreground, your App being paused, the tag going out of range and coming back in to range before your App has had a chance to be resumed and thus the OS thinks that nothing is waiting for an Intent from it and thus opens it's own window display a basic screen for NDEF data, instead of trying to pass the Intent to your still paused Activity.

The other suggestion is not to use NDEF format if you can do so easily because the OS understands NDEF it will try and do things with it, using your own format means the OS is less likely to interfere with what you are doing. BUT there is more complication if you want to write more than a page of data, but you do get better error handling capabilities.

With `enableReaderMode` your App does not get paused when the card is read (instead the card interaction is handled in a separate thread in your app), you get control of the sound, so you can play a sound when you have finished writing instead of when the task is half done.

Example of low level reading `enableReaderMode` in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59397667/2373819  writing pages is not much different in structure to reading.

**Update:**
Re-reading your code, it seems that when you write you are assuming the tag is in range. Because the tag can go in and out or range easily and frequently it is much more reliable to write as soon as `onNewIntent` is fired.

You should treat `onNewIntent` as a notification that a tag is in range for you to read or write from/to the tag (in the `enableReaderMode` method it is called `onTagDiscovered` because that is really what it is.)

**Update:**
Added a flow chart on how I handle read/write logic for reliable writing.
[image: Read/Write Logic]

Comment: But if I use "enableReaderMode" instead of "enableForegroundDispatch" I will be able to open the application with tag content (for example in textview)?

Comment: Yes you can display the tag contents in a textview, you just need to remember that the code is not running on the UI thread so you need to use `runOnUiThread` to set the text on the textview.

Comment: I was able to read from onNewIntent / onTagDiscovered and i have two more question.
1) When i try write to tag gets the message "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.nfc.tech.Ndef.connect ()' on a null object reference" whats going on?
2) How can I read the content of the tag from onTagDiscovered

Comment: 1) It sounds like your call to `get` on the Tag before the `connect` returned `null`, the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html#get(android.nfc.Tag) say "Returns null if Ndef was not enumerated in Tag#getTechList. This indicates the tag is not NDEF formatted, or that this tag is NDEF formatted but under a vendor specification that this Android device does not implement. " so the card might not be formatted for NDEF?

Comment: 2) In my low level NfcA example with `enableReaderMode` I have turned of the OS from doing NDEF parsing with the option `NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK`
You might not want to do this, then you could use the `getCachedNdefMessage` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.html#getCachedNdefMessage() for your read instead or leave that option on and `connect` and `getNdefMessage` instead

Comment: Thanks for your help, the key was deletion NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK from flags in enableReaderMode