# Workflow for using NTAG213 NFC to Identify Gym Members

Tags: android, nfc

What is the general workflow that I would develop to use wristbands equipped with NTAG213 NFC in order to authenticate gym members.

Currently in our database we have a "CardCode" field.  In actuality it is named Barcode, but that is because the current method of authenticating is showing a barcode to a scanner that corresponds with a unique member.

Is the general workflow NTAG213 that I would "write" this member identifying information to the tag and then when that member tries to check-in it would attempt to read this field.

My previous experience with radio technology are RFID tags that would come pre-written from manufacturer with a site code and card code.   Different vendors have different arrangements of the bits for site code, card code, and parity bits - so you have to know the bit format to read the tags and authenticate the member.

I get the feeling that the NTAG213 works more like a disk, I use a password from the MFG to be able to write to the NTAG213 and my readers use the information to authenticate.  I suppose with this type of tech it would be unreasonable to have the MFG to pre-write something?  I really don't know what the flow is.

For bonus, any example code with android.nfc would be awesome (I'm targeting Newland Nquire 304 (Android Kitkat 4.4)[image]

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is the [Tag's datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NTAG213_215_216.pdf)

At the low level the tag acts like a 2 dimensional array of memory 4 bytes wide and varying lengths.

As it is NFC Type 2 compliant you can use the NFC standard NDEF data encoding format and various OS's have methods to write NDEF encoded data without you having to worry about fitting the data correctly in to the 2 dimensional memory array.

Most cards come from the factory blank (but some vendors can add data to them for you with a cost).

While NTAG213 usually come from the factory with no password set on them, you have to set your own. The password can be set for write operations or both read and write operations.

The cards can also be made NDEF read-only but I would not recommend that, instead use the password.

How you use them depends on the level of security that is needed (to stop people cloning the cards to share one gym membership) and on if you want customers to read their own tags or if only certain hardware is required to read the tags that is tightly controlled.

Generally I would limit the hardware that can read/write to the tag, then you can set a password on read and write operations.

Then there would be 2 workflows.

**New member**

1. Get blank tag
2. configure the password for read and write
3. Authenticate with password
4. format the card for Ndef
5. Encode the data you want on the card using one or more Ndef records, at minimum, this should be your own Unique ID (Never use the Tag's UID as these are not Unique and can be cloned and are not protected by the password)

**Gym checkin**

1. Authenticate with password
2. Read the data from the Tag (At least the Unique ID you have written to the Tag)

I would recommend you use the `ènableReaderMode` Android API to tag detection, some code for that at https://stackoverflow.com/a/59397667/2373819

There are a lot of examples out there that use the older Android API `enableForegroundDispatch` but this is less reliable especially for writing data.

Overall you need to make sure decisions about what you want to store on the Tag and how you want to use it before you can decide how to write the code, otherwise the question is to big to answer in detail.

Comment: I'm targeting Android KitKat 4.4 because that is the OS of the Newland Nquire 304.

Comment: `enableReaderMode` is API 19 (KitKat 4.4) and above (though you can use the older API as well, you just have less control and it has some downsides and is less reliable for writing cards)

Comment: Do you think NTAG213 is the appropriate radio tech to use for our application.  Should we be looking for something cheaper or with less capability?

Comment: The Ntag 21x series of tags is not targetted at ticketing type applications, their security is not good enough for that, the more expensive like the Desfire tags are targeted at ticketing type applications. So it depends on your security requirements, but they are a good cheap and compatible type Tag (I would not use the Mifare Classic type tags as these are less compatible)