# how can i read and write on iso 14443 cards?

Tags: nfc, card

I'm trying my hand at using iso 14443 cards. I can't find a way to read or write on them via android app. Anyone have any solutions?

For now I have downloaded android apps like NFC tools, but I'm not very smart in using them.

Comment: You really need to be more specific on the make and model of the iso 14443 Cards as there are so many different  technologies that use iso 14443 for various parts that it is hard to answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.
Can you tell me how to get this information? The most I can get is what the NFC tools detect me.

Comment: A good start is just to read the card with NFC tools or NXP TagInfo Apps, on NFC Tools details of the Full Tag Type detected and the "Technologies Available" will help.

Comment: Those are the informations that i got from NXP TagInfo in my android device.
https://imgur.com/a/6qavUSU

Comment: OK, so the datasheet for the Tag is https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-SLE66R01L_DataBook_2019-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4627aa5d4f5017ac90258546472 and that gives a lot more info about how to use this particular Tag. It's sort of a Type 2 Tag but is not fully compliant, but the datasheet give the byte arrays needed to `transceive`  to it.

Answer (score 0):

So as these are sort of like Type 2 NfcA Tags (though not fully Type 2 compliant) and have a [datasheet](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-SLE66R01L_DataBook_2019-DataSheet-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4627aa5d4f5017ac90258546472) of what commands they support and what their memory organisation is like.

So to read and write data to these Tags you need to `transceive` a byte array containing the right commands and then you will receive back another byte array with the results of the command.

So [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59397667/2373819) is an example of how to `transceive` to NfcA on Android.

So your Tag does not support the `Fast Read` (`0x3A`) command used in this example but does support a more standard `Read` command

e.g. send the byte array

`0x30,0x00` to read the first 4 blocks of data (16 bytes) from the Tag (see section 6.2.1 of the datasheet and note the CRC is calculated for you.)

A write command begins with `0xA2,0x05` with 4 more bytes of data to write to the first user data area memory block

Comment: First of all; how can I use the code (sent by you) to be able to read the data of my card on my android smartphone?
After I have learned this I will be able to think about writing in the card.

Comment: Hopefully you have the basics of Android development before moving on to a more advanced topic of writing apps that use NFC, so you can build an App around the code I referenced and adjust it to exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes perfect, I should have the basic skills of android with java.  Then I'll get to work.  Thank you.