# Write UID on mifare 1k (ISO14443A, mifare classic 1K cards)

Tags: nfc, rfid, mifare

I recently bought a 13.56 mhz magic card with a writable UID.
The card has the following specs ;

[image: NFC Tool tag info]

I would like to clone my old card into the new one. I tried with the MCT app, and it seemed to be working, but when I scanned the card again, the UID was still the original one.
I found that some card need custom commands, so I'm currently trying to use the NFC tool app, with a custom command, to send in the new UID, without success.

I am aware that the MCT app can only write some specific magic card, but i don't exactly know what kind of card i have.
Could someone explain me how to figure out what kind of card i have ? What kind of card I can use with the MCT app ?

I read this thread, but it didn't help me : [how can i read and write on iso 14443 cards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71435279/how-can-i-read-and-write-on-iso-14443-cards)

Comment: May be because it's off topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  as it is not about software development it's about configuring hardware

Comment: I posted that on electronic stack exchange, is it the right place ?

Answer (score 0):

I have done that a long time ago, but i remember a few things. You need to format the card, and then use the MCT app to clone it. You'll find a CLONE UID section in the app.

Comment: I wasn't sure on this step, the vendor said it was already formatted, and ready to use. Secondly no, the MCT app didn't work, and i can't find what card it can write that's why i'm posting ???